# Dataflow polling not being able to see new entries

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-datastream

I have a dataflow job (created from the template datastream to spanner)running which is fetching new entries in json format from a cloud storage to insert them into spanner database, the new entries are in json format which are saved in the cloud storage from a datastream which listens from a mysql database (any inserts updates or deletes),
it has been happening that everything works okay but then after some time (it can be minutes, hours, days, I have tested them in different intervals) it just stops being able to see the new results, and seeing the logs of the worker it just prints this:

```
current round of polling took 119 ms and returned 5 results, of which 0 were new
```

but it already has alot more results that it should be polling, what could cause the dataflow to stop being able to see the new results?

EDIT:

I have being reading more carefully each option of the dataflow configuration, this one I think is the cause of this behaviour:

[image]

what I understand is that everytime a directory is created in the storage because of some event, the dataflow will start watching it for 10 minutes and get all the changes that happen there, but after those 10 minutes if something happens and gets for some reason inside that directory, the dataflow will not see it anymore, so I believe I should increase this parameter

Comment: Have you modified the code of the template? Without access to the source code, it will be difficult to help you. If anything, double check that your implementation is similar to the [Beam recommended pattern for watching files](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/#continuous-read-mode)

Comment: No, I am trying to get everything working without using java or python, only using the google console frontend, thanks for the code snippets I have been increasing the parameter "directoryWatchDurationInMinutes" and it is working as expected, with 30 minutes of watch but im going to use 60 minutes like on the code snippet you gave me (thank you), right now im only missing how to do transformations to finish